# Referencing relative sheet in VLOOKUP using INDIRECT

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to reference *current sheet* - 3 as the table_array in a Vlookup function. The problem is I don't have a cell with the name of the sheet to reference directly to. So instead I'm referencing a cell value (today's date) - 3. That is the name of the sheet I need to reference. I've added in a TEXT function to convert to mm/dd/yyyy format as that is the format the sheet name is in. The issue I'm having is the TEXT function is leaving an extra " in front of the date. I don't know if I've been staring at this too long but I cannot figure out why this is happening, please help.

```
=VLOOKUP(B3,INDIRECT("'"&TEXT((B3-3),"mm/dd/yyyy")&"'!"&"B3:W300"),12,0)
```

When I evaluate the formula, he TEXT function including concatenated "'" and "'!" become

```
"'01/07/2020'!"
```

This ends as

```
"'01/07/2020'!
```

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
=VLOOKUP(B3,INDIRECT(TEXT(B3-3,"'mm/dd/yyyy'!")&"B3:W300"),12,0)
 'or
=VLOOKUP(B3,INDIRECT(TEXT(B3-3,"'mm/dd/yyyy'!\B\3\:\W\3\0\0")),12,0)
```